# Is there a name for fingered (non-fingerless) gloves that have open parts for the back of the hand?

Tags: gloves

I couldn't find a picture sorry but I swear I've seen em before!

I'm talking about gloves that have fingers but also vents/gaps at the back of the hand to let the sweat evaporate. Your fingers get cold, but your hands get sweaty. What are these kinds of gloves called?

Comment: Backless gloves?

Answer (score 3):

Driving gloves? [Fancy Ferrari version](https://store.ferrari.com/en-us/regular-gloves_cod7789028784408615.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_Y7bn96t5QIVksJkCh3YJwDDEAQYAyABEgIa4_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&tp=158131&utm_campaign=Shopping_US&utm_medium=CPC&utm_source=Google)

I don't think I've seen cycling specific gloves in that configuration. However, if you want full finger cycling gloves, there are Mountain bike gloves used for racing that ventilate pretty well due to the lightweight fabrics used. They don't have an open back, but otherwise work well.

Comment: Some mtb gloves have a mesh back, like many fingerless bike gloves. This isn't noticeably warmer than an open back on fingerless

Answer (score 3):

Like [these](https://www.wiggle.co.uk/giro-lx-mitts/), but long fingered?

Hang on, found one: like [this](https://www.wiggle.co.uk/race-face-womens-khyber-gloves-2016/).

I assume the cut-out used to be needed to avoid bunching due to the wrist fastening, and that was needed before they could just make the whole thing out of stretchy mesh.

Anyway, in both cases they're just described as gloves.